# How to access TextMeshProUGUI in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas with a button and a "TextMeshPro - Text" component. When I click the button I want to update the text of the textMeshPro component. This is the code I'm using:

```
var canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
var tmp = canvas.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
Debug.Log(tmp);
```

tmp is null but why? In the inspector I see it's an "RectTransform" with "Text Mesh Pro UGUI (Script)". I can access the RectTransform in the script but not the TextMeshProUGUI component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Canvas` is the *parent* of the text object

You need to either use `transform.GetChild()`, `transform.Find()` or `GetComponentInChildren<>()`